# multi-column primary keys with IN statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy has a very nice facility called `selectinload` which selects relationships automatically emitting a second query for an arbitrary (<500) number of parent objects by emitting a query of the following shape (with multi-column PKs):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM parent as parent_1 JOIN child on child.parent_id = parent_1.id
WHERE (parent.pk1, parent.pk2) IN ((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), ...);
```

The problem is that MySQL doesn't seem to use indexes for multi-column `IN` statements if there's more than one tuple on the right side. Here's two explains of the same query, first with a single element on the right of the `IN`, and then with two elements. Notice the number of scanned rows:

```sql
MySQL [mydb]> explain SELECT * FROM orders AS orders_1 INNER JOIN line_items ON orders_1.id = line_items.order_id WHERE (orders_1.account_id, orders_1.shop_name) in ((1, 'foo'));
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys                                                                         | key      | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | orders_1   | ref  | PRIMARY,code_UNIQUE,shop_name,id_idx,account_id,account_date_utc_idx,account_date_idx | PRIMARY  | 4       | const            |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | line_items | ref  | order_id,order_id_warehouse                                                           | order_id | 5       | mydb.orders_1.id |    1 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+------------------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.119 sec)

MySQL [mydb]> explain SELECT * FROM orders AS orders_1 INNER JOIN line_items ON orders_1.id = line_items.order_id WHERE (orders_1.account_id, orders_1.shop_name) in ((1, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'));
+----+-------------+------------+------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+------------------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys               | key      | key_len | ref              | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+------------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | orders_1   | ALL  | code_UNIQUE,id_idx          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL             | 70865635 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | line_items | ref  | order_id,order_id_warehouse | order_id | 5       | mydb.orders_1.id |        1 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+------------+------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+------------------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.099 sec)
```

This doesn't happen if the `IN` is a single column, in this case, at least up to a number of entries, it uses the index.

Does anyone know what's going on here, if there's anything that can be done short of changing the table's PK?

As another option, is there a way of manually setting a relationship's items on Alchemy, so I can load them in a smarter way?

Comment: @Strawberry 1. the name is figurative, 2. 'pk22' is supposed to represent a value, not a column name, 3. it's supposed to represent "PK column-2 of the second object", not "22nd PK column"

Comment: @Strawberry as in, the whole issue here is with composite PKs, so I made an example with 2 columns for a PK

Comment: @Strawberry does that look better? A minimal example would imply a schema, and populating the table with enough rows for the `EXPLAIN` to show it's scanning the whole table XD

Comment: Much better. The question makes a more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

It's tedious, but I'm afraid I think you're right.

If performance is critical, then look at something like this;

```
SELECT c.olumns
     , y.ou 
     , a.ctually
     , n.eed
  FROM parent parent_1 
  JOIN child c
    on c.parent_id = parent_1.id
 WHERE (parent_1.pk1 = 1 AND parent_1.pk2 = 'foo') 
    OR (parent_1.pk1 = 2 AND parent_1.pk2 = 'bar');
```

Comment: I know that, but that's not the way Alchemy works, and I don't know what to do. Specifically, making the queries manually will not populate the relationships that are handled as lists in python, which is the whole point of this